# Removing currency symbol, except on Woocommerce cart and checkout pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, price

I want to remove the currency symbol from my webshop, except on the shopping-cart page and the checkout.

So I do NOT want a currency symbol on:

- category pages
- product pages
- home page
- landing pages
- blogs

But I DO want the currency symbol on:

- shopping cart
- checkout pages
- confirmation e-mail

I have been given this code:

```
function avia_remove_wc_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    if ( !is_cart() || !is_checkout()){
        $currency_symbol = '';
        return $currency_symbol;
    }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'avia_remove_wc_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
```

Which removes the currency symbol from all pages. It doesn't make it reappear on the shopping cart or checkout pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    function avia_remove_wc_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) 
    {
        $currency_symbol = '';
        if ( is_cart() || is_checkout()) 
            $currency_symbol = '$';
        return $currency_symbol;
    } 
    add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'avia_remove_wc_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. The currency symbol is still missing on every single page. Do you know if this code looks at the identity of the page, of the URL name? Perhaps the automatic translation for Woocommerce is changing "is_cart" into something else? (just thinking out loud here)

Comment: I made some changes to my answer. Can you check if that works?

Comment: It seems to work perfectly. I would need to do some more testing to be 100% sure, but I just did a fake-order and everything works just as I want. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the currency symbol **on view order pages (My account) and on email notifications too**, you should do it this way:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'avia_remove_wc_currency_symbol', 10, 2);
function avia_remove_wc_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() )
        $currency_symbol = '';

    return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

Tested and works

> Is also better to let the `$currency_symbol` argument (defined in Woocommerce settings or with somme multi currency plugins) to have the hand where it needs to be shown and not handwrite it in the filter.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on this. If I won't use, somebody who comes here via Google can make good use of it.

Comment: @VinnieVanRooij thanks … your code was nearly correct, you should just have to put the return out of the if statement…